# Get advertisement data from peripheral object?

Tags: ios, ios8, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

If I already have a `peripheral` object, it doesn't seem there is any way to get the advertising data from it. I can only get the advising data from:

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
```

Is there any way to get it from the `peripheral` object after it's been stored in a variable, long after the delegate call above?

Comment: No, because the advertisement is different to the peripheral. The advertisement is ephemeral.

Comment: Note that some peripheral may stop completely to advertise when connected to another device.